# Getting distinct combination of two columns

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, grails, groovy

Using Hibernate, I want to get the rows of values such that:

```
col1   | col2
-------+-------
   1   |    2
-------+-------
   2   |    1
-------+-------
   3   |    4
-------+-------
   4   |    5
-------+-------
   4   |    3
```

will produce:

```
col1   | col2
-------+-------
   1   |    2
-------+-------
   3   |    4
-------+-------
   4   |    5
```

Can I get this out in Hibernate on grails? Or can anyone provide a MySQL implementation of this. Been battling this long enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use mysql [least()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) and [greatest()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) operators to make sure that the smaller number comes first and the highest comes later. This way you can use distinct to eliminate duplicates:

```
select distinct least(col1, fol2) as col1, greatest(col1, col2) as col2
from yourtable
```

Comment: In my case, the actual values in the columns are phone numbers, does this still work?

Comment: Yep, it will, since MySQL can order strings as well, not just numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can group the two column like :

select * from yourtable group by (col1+col2);